# How to make fullpage.js fit page with fixed navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

My problem is that my fixed bootstrap navigation is covering 60px (the navigation's height) of my page, so it's screwing op the "padding" of the columns I have.

I tried to put margin: 60px on .section, but it just pushes the page 60px down, not resizing the page by 60px. Instead there is 60px hidden at the bottom.

There is no padding-top/bottom defined on the columns. They are defined with display: flex and align-items: center, with a div inside containing the text so it will be centered all time.

https://jsfiddle.net/fmcq9wpn/7/

CSS:

```
.col-lg-6 {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        .text {
            padding: 0 5%;
            h3 {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
            p {
                line-height: 2.0;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section news">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="picture col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="text">

                    <p>Mandag 27. Januar, 2019</p>
                    <H3>COACHING-FOREDRAGSRÆKKE PÅ UNIVERSITET</H3>
                    <p>Har man lyst til at vide mere om coaching fra forskellige, faglige perspektiver, arrangerer
                        professor
                        Reinhardt Stelter en foredragsrække på . . .</p>
                    <br> <button>Læs mere</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="news-box col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="text">
                    <p>Torsdag 5. Februar, 2019</p>
                    <h3>SIKKEN FEST!</h3>
                    <p>Tak til alle gæster, som kom og fejrede det nye års ankomst sammen med os! Det blev en
                        vidunderlig
                        fredag . . .</p><br>
                    <button>Læs mere</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cpenhagen Coaching Center</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#education">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#testimonial">Testimonial</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#news">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#signup">Sign up</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-proofer-ignore href="/#footer">Footer</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

It's like the .section will always be the same size as the window.

I have a picture here: https://ibb.co/BgskKSb showing the layout.

Comment: I think `.section` needs to be `height: calc(100vh - 60px);`, with the 60px of margin-top.

Comment: I tried it but it still pushes the page 60px down. I have tried to put a defined height on .section but it does not change anything.

Comment: Can you try replicating this in a snippet so we can see it happening?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fmcq9wpn/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fullpage.js option `paddingTop`.
For example:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
   paddingTop: '60px'
});
```

Comment: Where should this be placed?

Comment: Before the closing body in a script tag.